# scraper filters out word's instead of line

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I was trying to make a filter that filter's out the crap from this scrape, but I have an issue where it filters out the words. I would like to filter out the whole line instead of the words.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import os

def Scrape():
    page = input("Page: ")

    url = "https://openuserjs.org/?p=" + page

    source = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'lxml')

    os.system('cls')

    Filter(soup)

def Filter(soup):
    crap = ""
    f = open("Data/Crap.txt", "r")
    for craptext in f:
        crap = craptext
    for Titles in soup.select("a.tr-link-a>b"):
        print(Titles.text.replace(crap, "").strip())

while True:
    Scrape()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
print(Titles.text.replace(crap, "").strip())
```

Try using:

```
if crap not in Titles.text:
    print(Titles.text.strip())
```